# Делаю телеграм бота и не могу понять как узнать нажал ли юзер на url кнопку или нет? Мне нужно отправить сообщение юзеру если он нажал на кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

```
import telebot
if message.chat.type == 'group':
keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item_joingame = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Присоединиться', 
url='t.me/mafiapetrushkaa_bot')
keyboard1.add(item_joingame)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ведется набор в игру') #
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, это сделать с URL кнопкой нельзя. Используйте для этого Callback кнопки

Comment: георгий можете помочь мне с еще одним вопросом перейдите на мой профиль и посмотрите второй вопрос пожалуйста